# Add CSS File To Layout Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I'm trying to add a css file in my zend application `layout.php` the problem is it resides in

> /application/media/css/style.css

when i do

```
 <?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/media/css/style.css')  ?>
```

it generates the path like

> appname/public/media/css/style.css

where as i need to generate the path like

> appname/application/media/css/style.css

how can i tell zend to look for the css file at a apecific location in layout.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in application directory is not accessible via your web server you would either have to move the file to the public directory or setup a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to it.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved the problem. Always is simple. :D 
I added

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
```

in head tag. And css folder is in public folder.

thanks
ohm

Comment: thanks @ ohm but i guess that is the same solution @nav has provided

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete all the answers, is not "correct" put your CSS, JS, fonts, and all other media in 'application' folder.  The 'public' folder is there for that. 
Then, to remove the '/public' from all your URLs, just make a simple change in your  **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / # you could put some subfolder, if you need
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

And in your **index.php**

```
<?php

define('RUNNING_FROM_ROOT', true);
include 'public/index.php';
```

And then you could use this to append your styles

```
<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/public/media/css/style.css')  ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks!  Not sure why this isn't accepted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<?=$this->baseUrl();?>/yourpathtocss" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way is to do this from layout.phtml as follows

`<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/site.css') ?>`

Answer (score 0):

here 'TestZend' is Project name

```
<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/TestZend/public/css/bootstrap.css'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code snippet in the layout  section to make sure the MEDIA folder is created inside `yourProjectFoder/public/media/css/style.css`

```
<head>
  // some code here...
  <?= $this->headLink() 
    //added from the new template   
    ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('media/css/style.css'))

  ?>
  // some other code here
</head>
```